# I want to get the rooms type which are not already select?

Tags: mysql

## Table 1 (Room Types)

type_id type_name

## Table 2 (Rooms)

room_id room_type_id room_property_id

i want to get only those room types which are not included in the rooms table according to property_id

## This is what i have done so far

```
SELECT `rt`.`type_id`,
       `rt`.`type_name`
FROM `ae_room_type` AS `rt`
WHERE type_id NOT IN (
                        (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(room_type_id)
                         FROM ae_rooms
                         WHERE room_properties_id = '5dea0ab1-e527-4882-a2df-9c592ea826a4'))
```

Comment: What result do you get with your SQL?

Comment: i have 4 room types with the id 1,2,3,4 and the that property have 2 rooms in the database with different room types but it returns 3 room types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple approach is a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM room_types t1
LEFT JOIN rooms t2
    ON t1.type_id = t2.room_type_id AND
       t2.room_properties_id = '5dea0ab1-e527-4882-a2df-9c592ea826a4'
WHERE t2.room_type_id IS NULL;
```

The idea here is that we try to join each room type record to the rooms table.  Those room types which never appear in the rooms table would have nothing to join to.  In this case, such records would only appear once in the result set, not duplicated.  A `null` value in the rooms table after the join is the marker for a room type which has not been used in any room.

Comment: I was writing the same answer but he want a specific room_properties_id which doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @DanielE. I think my answer can be saved by just adding a second join condition on that `room_properties_id`.  This second condition would mean that the room type has to be used in certain types of room, otherwise that type would appear as unused in the result set.

Comment: The above answer is what i am looking for sorry my english is not good

Comment: @FarhanJameelAhmed Uh...my query should give you that logic...did you bother to try it?

Answer (score 0):

You should also use a subquery to filter the desired room properties, and then use a LEFT JOIN with an IS NULL condition to get only the types not included in the remaining rooms:

```
SELECT rt.type_id, 
       rt.type_name
FROM   ae_room_type as rt 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT room_properties_id, 
                  room_type_id
           FROM ae_rooms 
           WHERE room_properties_id = '5dea0ab1-e527-4882-a2df-9c592ea826a4') AS r
ON     rt.type_id = r.room_type_id
WHERE  r.room_type_id IS NULL
```